# contract not storing data during foundry testing

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry

I mainly use hardhat and mocha for testing but this time I was using foundry for testing (in hardhat project). While testing I realized it's not storing data in contract.

I was building a token listing protocol and storing data in structs. It's working fine when I use hardhat and mocha but it's not storing data while foundry testing.

Could someone help me out? It's showing this

```
Running 1 test for test/foundry/ListToken.t.sol:ListTokenTest
[FAIL. Reason: Assertion failed.] testStoresData() (gas: 3709070)
Logs:
  Error: a == b not satisfied [uint]
    Expected: 1200000000000000000000
      Actual: 0
```

Here's my foundry testing file.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "../../contracts/P2P.sol";
import "../../contracts/test-token/GenericERC20.sol";
import "forge-std/console.sol";

contract ListTokenTest is Test {
    P2P public p2p;
    GenericERC20 public dai;
    GenericERC20 public usdc;
    GenericERC20 public weth;
    uint256 public constant PRICE = 1200 ether;
    uint256 public constant AMOUNT = 10 ether;
    uint256 public constant LIMIT = 3 ether;

    function setUp() public {
        p2p = new P2P();
        dai = new GenericERC20("DAI", "DAI", 18);
        usdc = new GenericERC20("USDC", "USDC", 6);
        weth = new GenericERC20("WETH", "WETH", 18);
    }

    function testStoresData() public {
        vm.prank(msg.sender);
        this.setUp();
        p2p.listToken(address(weth), address(dai), PRICE, AMOUNT, LIMIT);
        P2P.Listing memory listing = p2p.getListing(msg.sender, address(weth), address(dai));

        assertEq(listing.price, PRICE);

        // assertEq(listing.amount, AMOUNT);
        // assertEq(listing.limit, LIMIT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the following:

```
vm.prank(msg.sender);
this.setUp();
p2p.listToken(address(weth), address(dai), PRICE, AMOUNT, LIMIT);
P2P.Listing memory listing = p2p.getListing(msg.sender, address(weth), address(dai));
assertEq(listing.price, PRICE);
```

Like [@rolandsaven says](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/138290/114658), `prank(..)` is only applied to the next call. As a result here the `prank` is applied in the `this.setUp()` call, instead of the `listToken` call. The easy solution is to move `prank(..)` before the `listToken` call.

```
this.setUp();
vm.prank(msg.sender);
p2p.listToken(address(weth), address(dai), PRICE, AMOUNT, LIMIT);
P2P.Listing memory listing = p2p.getListing(msg.sender, address(weth), address(dai));
assertEq(listing.price, PRICE);
```

However, there's a small mistake here, which is that `setUp()` is always called implicitly *once* when your test is initialized, like `beforeEach` in mocha, and the post-state is cached. So you don't need to call it again, like you do.

So the "best" way to write this test actually would've been by removing `this.setUp()` and `prank` usage, and replacing `msg.sender` with `address(this)`:

```
p2p.listToken(address(weth), address(dai), PRICE, AMOUNT, LIMIT);
P2P.Listing memory listing = p2p.getListing(address(this), address(weth), address(dai));
assertEq(listing.price, PRICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vm.prank()` cheatcode sets `msg.sender` **for the next call** ([more here](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/prank)). I reckon the problem lies in not calling the `listToken()` method with the correct address.

The default `msg.sender` of a foundry test is [0x00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/config/testing?highlight=0x00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72#general). It seems like you are calling `listToken()` with this address and expecting `getListing()` to return the listing from the `msg.sender`.

I'd recommend either using `vm.startPrank(msg.sender)` and `vm.stopPrank()`
([more here](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/start-prank)) in their appropriate places wrapping the functions you'd like to call with `msg.sender` OR adding `vm.prank(msg.sender)` just right before those calls.

*Note that I'm unfamiliar with what lies inside those functions, so if I'm not right please share and I'll amend my answer.*